# how to see encrypted password stored in laravel and show in admin dashboard page

Tags: laravel, authentication, hash, password-encryption

I want to show the password from database which is encrypted.
How to show envrypted password in admin dashboard page?
I have seen laravel documentation fo rehashing but i am not understanding it

Comment: Repeat after me: "A hash is not encryption. We store password hashes."

Comment: @JonathonReinhart A hash is not encryption. We store password hashes.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart A hash is not encryption. We store password hashes.

Comment: A hash is not encryption. We store password hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel **hashes** passwords, which is irreversible. You pretty much can't ever see a password once it's been hashed and stored in the database, and this is by design.  **It isn't encrypted**, and thus, cannot be decrypted.

When someone signs in to the application, their password is HASHED, and then compared with the hash in the database.  This is done so that a password can not be stolen from the database.

Now, I don't know your application or your circumstances, but I would consider it very bad practice to allow even an admin access to users' passwords (there shouldn't be a reason in the world they need to see those).

[Here's a great video on the matter.](https://youtu.be/8ZtInClXe1Q)

But if you REALLY still need this to happen, consider a making a custom authentication driver that at least uses encryption instead of hashing (but again, probably a bad idea).  I found a few different tutorials [with a quick google search](http://laravel.io/forum/11-04-2014-laravel-5-how-do-i-create-a-custom-auth-in-laravel-5).